# NHibernate returning duplicate object in child collections when using Fetch

Tags: nhibernate

When doing a query like this (using Nhibernate 2.1.2):

```
 ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyRootType>()
                .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection1", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection2", FetchMode.Eager)
                .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id));
```

I am getting multiple duplicate objects in some cartesian fashion.  E.g. if `ChildCollection1` has 3 elements, and `ChildColection2` has 2 elements then I get results with each element in `ChildColection1` one duplicated, and each element in `ChildColection2` triplicated!  This was a bit of a WTF moment for me...

**So how to do this correctly?**

- Is using SetFetchMode like this only supported when specifying one collection?
- Am I just using it wrong (I've seen some references to results transformers, but imagined this would be simplier).
- Is this something that's different in NH3?

---

**Update:**

As per Felice's suggestion, I tried using the DistinctRootEntity transformer, but this is still returning duplicates. Code:

```
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyRootType>()
                .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection1", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection2", FetchMode.Eager)
                .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id));

 criteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

 return criteria.UniqueResult<MyRootType>();
```

Comment: still no way to do this ?

Comment: Check if this works (I have only tested it with QueryOver on NH 3, but it seems to be the same): http://stackoverflow.com/a/19717548/806975

Answer (score 15):

You can select single distinct results by specifying `SetResultsTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);`

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at that.  Do you know why this is not the default behaviour?  Who would want the duplicates?!

Comment: This is the same question I asked when I faced your problem. Not a real answer, but let's think what happen in the query side: the resulting recordset will contain duplicates, and NH mimic this background behavior. In any case NH internally uses the same entity, they are only duplicated entries into the returned list.

Comment: @Felice Pollano, just added the resultstransformer.  Unfortunately this did not change anything for me - I'm still getting the duplicates.  Perhaps this is down to the type of collection?

Comment: collection type should not matter. Try to post the code you used for apply the transformer.

Comment: your code is correct, so there should be something different. Does things change if you use Lazy instead of eager ? If still duplicates, maybe there is something wrong in the mapping.

Comment: I'll try, but by default my mappings are lazy, so the fetchmode will be redundant.

Comment: DistinctRootEntity only applies to *root* entities, which is not the problem here.

Comment: Mauricio yes correct I did not see the whole code the first time.

Comment: @FrancoisBotha: It also works for me as long as I only have one join, the moment I have 3 joins it stops working.

Comment: NHibernate 4.0.4., I have 8 joins and 3 child collections in my query and this did the trick for me! Problems with queries (for me) start with too deep levels of join fetches of collections (child collection elements having collections and those items having another collections and so on). For "simple" scenarios, it just saved my day.

Answer (score 11):

You're doing a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) here. Don't. Instead, [fetch each collection separately](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx).

BTW: this isn't something NHibernate-specific, the same applies to any ORM in any platform, or even pure SQL without any ORM at all. In general, you don't want to fetch N*M rows when you can fetch N+M instead.

Comment: What if you were fetching 1000 entries instead of a unique result?  Surely two JOINs (Cartesian product) in a single SQL query is more efficient than 2001 selects, even if it returns more rows (this depends in part on how large the collections are).

Comment: I may have jumped the gun--you are right in most cases.  It probably makes sense to issue two queries, one with a single join.

Comment: I used the Future methode to fix this, NH did the rest for me.

Answer (score 3):

I am not using NHibernate (rather, regular 'ol Hibernate), but in the Java version of Hibernate you can define One-To-Many collections as either Lists or Sets.  If you define them as Sets you will not get duplicates.  Surprisingly enough, this happens without overriding equals().  Unfortunately, I have the same problem and I want Lists so I can integrate with Wicket but no duplicates...

Answer (score 3):

What were you mapping your collection as? If your using a bag for example you will get duplicates. You can use a set instead and you won't get duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Futures](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures):

```
ICriteria criteriaFuture1
    = session.CreateCriteria<MyRootType>()
        .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection1", FetchMode.Eager)
        .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id))
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .FutureValue<MyRootType>();
 ICriteria criteriaFuture2
    = session.CreateCriteria<MyRootType>()
        .SetFetchMode("ChildCollection2", FetchMode.Eager)
        .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(id))
        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .FutureValue<MyRootType>();

 return criteriaFuture1.Value;
```